# Javascript functions and codes not working in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to use a date-picker and cascading dropdown lists for some days now without success. The normal mvc date-picker isn't working in my project so I tried using the bootstrap one, when it failed I wrote a javascript function which failed too.
In the case of the dropdown lists, the function is simply not called. When the javascripts codes didn't work in bundle form I wrote the directly into my code. I can see the js scripts in my browser though
This is how it looks now

```js
@section Calen{
    <script>
        $('#DT').datepicker({ format: 'mm/dd/yyyy', startDate: '-3d' });
    </script>
}

@section Sync{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ddlIl').change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/Users/GetIlce",
                    data: { Id: $('#ddlIl').val() },
                    datatype: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var ilce = "<select id='ddlIlce'>";
                        ilce = ilce + '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            ilce = ilce + '<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
                        }
                        district = district + '</select>';
                        $('#Ilceler').html(ilce);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="form-group date" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.DogumTarihi, "Doğum Tarihi")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DogumTarihi, new { @class = "form-control datecontrol", @id="DT"})
            </div>

 <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Iller, "Il")
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Iller, Model.Iller, "--Seçin--", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlIl" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Ilceler, "Ilce")
                      @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Ilceler, new List<SelectListItem>(), "--Seçin--", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlIlce" }) 
                    </div>
```

I render those scripts in my layout

```
@RenderSection("Calen", false)
@RenderSection("Sync", false)
```

Here is the html code generated

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register Page - Hastane Randevu</title>
    
    <link href="/content/styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/content/styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/content/styles/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Login</a>            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        
<h1>Yeni Admin ve Hastane</h1>
<form action="/Hastane/New" method="post"><div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div>    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Admin Bilgileri</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="KimlikNo">Kimlik No</label>
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The field KimlikNo must be a string or array type with a maximum length of &#39;12&#39;." data-val-maxlength-max="12" data-val-required="The KimlikNo field is required." id="KimlikNo" name="KimlikNo" type="text" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Username">Username</label>
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The field Username must be a string or array type with a maximum length of &#39;50&#39;." data-val-maxlength-max="50" data-val-required="The Username field is required." id="Username" name="Username" type="text" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Password">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Telefon">Telefon</label>
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Telefon field is required." id="Telefon" name="Telefon" type="text" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Email">Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The field Email must be a string or array type with a maximum length of &#39;256&#39;." data-val-maxlength-max="256" data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="Email" name="Email" type="email" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Cinsiyet</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="list-group">
                <div class="list-group-item" style="margin-left:70px">
                    <input id="Cinsiyetler_0__Id" name="Cinsiyetler[0].Id" type="hidden" value="1" />
                    <label for="Cinsiyetler_0__IsChecked">
                        <input id="Cinsiyetler_0__IsChecked" name="Cinsiyetler[0].IsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Cinsiyetler[0].IsChecked" type="hidden" value="false" />
                        Erkek
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item" style="margin-left:70px">
                    <input id="Cinsiyetler_1__Id" name="Cinsiyetler[1].Id" type="hidden" value="2" />
                    <label for="Cinsiyetler_1__IsChecked">
                        <input id="Cinsiyetler_1__IsChecked" name="Cinsiyetler[1].IsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Cinsiyetler[1].IsChecked" type="hidden" value="false" />
                        Kadin
                    </label>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


            <div class="form-group date" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
                <label for="DogumTarihi">Doğum Tarihi</label>
                <input class="form-control datecontrol" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field DogumTarihi must be a date." data-val-required="The DogumTarihi field is required." id="DT" name="DogumTarihi" type="text" value="01/01/0001 00:00:00" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Hastane Bilgileri</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Iller">Il</label>
                        <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Iller field is required." id="ddlIl" name="Iller"><option value="">--Se&#231;in--</option>
<option value="1">Edirne</option>
<option value="2">Bursa</option>
<option value="3">İstanbul</option>
<option value="4">Ankara</option>
</select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Ilceler">Ilce</label>
                      <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Ilceler field is required." id="ddlIlce" name="Ilceler"><option value="">--Se&#231;in--</option>
</select> 
                    </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="HastaneAdi">HastaneAdi</label>
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The HastaneAdi field is required." id="HastaneAdi" name="HastaneAdi" type="text" value="" />
            </div>

                    

                    <input type="submit" value="Kaydet" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    <a>ya da vazgeç</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>




        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2017 - Hastanemiz....</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/myDatePicker.js"></script>

    
    <script>
        $('#DT').datepicker({ format: 'mm/dd/yyyy', startDate: '-3d' });
    </script>

    
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ddlIl').change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/Users/GetIlce",
                    data: { Id: $('#ddlIl').val() },
                    datatype: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var ilce = "<select id='ddlIlce'>";
                        ilce = ilce + '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            ilce = ilce + '<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
                        }
                        district = district + '</select>';
                        $('#Ilceler').html(ilce);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
    

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Microsoft Edge","requestId":"170d14dffa0d4444907bf086ca9c0c5c"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:60203/39e10134efdf4b4eb0cfd336b4240aed/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you share the HTML that page is generating?

Comment: Do you get any errors in console window?

Comment: @kblok sure,  I just added it

Comment: @User3250 no, it's just as if they are ignored

Comment: @Ismael123 it looks like you are not including jquery.js, Am I right?

Comment: @kblok A letter was missing in my script bundle. I added it but my js are still ignored. I updated the html code generated for the page

Comment: I ran that as HTML, added a few alerts and the alerts are working. So the code is getting there, have you check the console output in your browser?

Comment: @kblok it says my datepicker is not a function but I solved it by moving it to my datepicker.js. And I got I syntax error in the jquery.js every time I clicked on the dropdownlist. I updated it to jquery.3,1,1.js which solved the syntax error but I now get an "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parents(...).andSelf is not a function" in the jquery still

Comment: Well so that change the Question you posted, I'd close it and create a new one if you need to

Comment: okay, thanks @kblok

Comment: The problem was caused by a missing character in the bundle config path

Answer (score 0):

What caused the problem was a missing character in my bundle config file xD